# MySQL error when creating tables through liquibase

Tags: mysql, grails, mysql-error-1064, liquibase

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 + MySQL 5.5 + Liquibase through the database-migration plugin 0.2.1.

When I'm in my development environment, I have Hibernate configured to use "create-drop" but in my QA environment, I want to use liquibase to create my tables. Here is my environments config:

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            configClass = GrailsAnnotationConfiguration.class
            pooled = false
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "root"
            password =  ""
            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dripita_dev"      
        }
    }
    localQa {
        dataSource {
            configClass=GrailsAnnotationConfiguration.class
            pooled=false
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username="root"
            password=""
            dialect="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dripita_localqa"        
        }
    }
 ...
}
```

When I bring the app up in dev mode, the database tables are create fine. I do the following to create the changelog:

```
$ grails dbm-generate-gorm-changelog changelog.groovy
```

Which looks like this:

```
changeSet(author: "javidjamae (generated)", id: "1309959832163-2") {
    createTable(tableName: "payment") {
        column(autoIncrement: "true", name: "id", type: "bigint") {
            constraints(nullable: "false", primaryKey: "true", primaryKeyName: "paymentPK")
        }

        column(name: "version", type: "bigint") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

        column(name: "buyer_id", type: "bigint") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

        column(name: "buyer_information_id", type: "bigint")

        column(name: "currency", type: "varchar(255)") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

        column(name: "discount_cart_amount", type: "decimal(19,2)") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

        column(name: "paypal_transaction_id", type: "varchar(255)")

        column(name: "status", type: "varchar(9)") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

        column(name: "tax", type: "double precision(19)") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

        column(name: "transaction_id", type: "varchar(255)")
    }
}
```

Then I try to create the tables from the changelog:

```
$ grails -Dgrails.env=localQa dbm-update
```

But, when I run the dbm-update, I get the following error:

```
07/06 08:52:41 INFO  [main]: liquibase  - Successfully acquired change log lock
07/06 08:52:42 INFO  [main]: liquibase  - Reading from `DATABASECHANGELOG`
07/06 08:52:42 INFO  [main]: liquibase  - Reading from `DATABASECHANGELOG`
07/06 08:52:42 ERROR [main]: liquibase  - Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE `payment` (`id` BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL, `version` BIGINT NOT NULL, `buyer_id` BIGINT NOT NULL, `buyer_information_id` BIGINT, `currency` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `discount_cart_amount` decimal(19,2) NOT NULL, `paypal_transaction_id` VARCHAR(255), `status` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, `tax` double precision(19) NOT NULL, `transaction_id` VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT `paymentPK` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL, `transaction_id` VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT `paymentPK` PRIMARY KEY (`' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
```

When I copy/paste the create statement in MySQL, I get the same error. I even took the ENGINE=InnoDB off to see if that made a difference, but it didn't. Any ideas?

FYI: I installed MySQL using HomeBrew on my Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your QA db doesn't know what the datatype `double precision(19)` is.
Try changing it to just `double precision`.

If that fails, consider using another datatype: The [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) says that double precision is a "nonstandard variation"

Comment: Thanks! That worked from the MySQL command line. In my domain object, that field is a BigDecimal, so I'm assuming that its a bug is either the db-migration plugin, or in Liquibase that it generates it as double precision(19). I'll file a bug report and see where I get with it.